# How to redirect hostname to appropriate language version

Tags: apache, zend-framework, dns, virtualhost

I want to redirect

```
http://en.example.org
http://de.example.org
```

to

```
http://example.org/en
http://example.org/de
```

but not like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public"
 ServerName example.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public/en"
 ServerName en.example.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public/de"
 ServerName de.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

since there is no such a folder "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public/en" or "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public/de"

Nor can I use :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public"
 ServerName example.org
 ServerAlias en.example.org de.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

since I need to reuse 'en', 'de' in zend framework.

Any idea?

Comment: So if you can't make vhosts for `en.example.org` and `de.example.org`, where do I go when I type those hostnames into my browser's URL address bar?

Comment: always here: "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public" And then zend framework takes charge. It takes 'en', 'de' as parameter in setup file named 'application.ini.'

Comment: I'm not a expert, so any possible way is welcome. Apache server level or zend framework level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what zend does with the requests. I assume there's an htaccess file in your document root that has some zend stuff in it, if so you'll want to add this before them.

To redirect the browser so it's URL address bar says `http://example.org/en`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.org/en/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.org/de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you just want to internally rewrite the URI, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/ 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /de/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However it's not what I wanted. I'm assuming there is no folder "en". To explain short (from your example), I want to append 'en' in front of ${REQUEST_URI}, so that C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/example/public/index.php handles 'en/blah/blah' instead of '/blah/blah' within the zend.